# How to use J2SE classes in blackberry application?

Tags: blackberry

I want to use java.io.FileInputStream, java.io.FileOutputStream, java.io.ObjectInputStream, java.io.ObjectOutputStream classes in my blackberry project. But blackberry supports J2ME[i.e. CLDC], which doesn't contain these classes. Is there any solution to this problem? How to use these classes in blackberry project? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the only way you could use J2SE classes in your project is to re-implement those classes using the provided J2ME core classes. This would be very messy, would probably take a long time and would be rather error prone but it could be done.

You are better served using the classes provided by the CLDC. It does affect code portability but...its a phone: there is a limit to how portable you're going to get.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. Does blackberry J2ME support CDC?

Comment: Not as far as I can tell: from http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/overview-summary.html, http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/index.html and http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/index.html you'll see that there is very limited support for the `java.io` package. Take a look and see if what those offer may be enough to do what you want.